# Convert string to list without elements being individual characters?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a function called `support` that counts the number of times passed items occur in elements in a list:

```
>>> rows = ['candy apple banana cookie', 'candy apple banana', 'candy', 'apple', 'apple banana candy', 'candy apple', 'banana']

>>> def support(item, rows):
        return float(sum([1 for row in rows if item in row]))

>>> print(support('apple', rows))
5.0
```

That works well, but eventually I'll need to measure how frequently **two** items occur together in the data. I could define something like this:

```
>>> def joint_support(items, rows):
        return float(sum([1 for row in rows if all(item in row.split() for item in items)]))
```

I'd rather not define two functions that effectively do the same thing. Whether the user passes one or two elements in `items`, I'd like for the function to count the occurrence of those items, either jointly or separately, in the data. Without using an `if` statement to measure the length of `items` (i.e. using a list comprehension), how can I make sure that, if the `items` parameter is just one string, that the function does not search for joint occurrence of each individual letter?

This is what I have so far:

```
>>> def master_support(items, rows):
return float(sum([1 for row in rows if all(item in row.split() for item in items if type(items) is not str) else 1 if items in row.split()]))
```

Effectively, I think I'm asking how I can automatically convert `str` to `list` without the elements of the list being individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you are searching for something like this

```
def joint_support(items, rows):
    return sum([1 for row in rows if set(items).issubset(set(row.split()))])
```

The second `set` is optional

```
rows = ['candy apple banana cookie', 'candy apple banana', 'candy', 'apple', 'apple banana candy', 'candy apple', 'banana']
rows2 = ['candy apple banana cookie']
items = ['apple', 'banana']

joint_support(items, rows)
joint_support(items, rows2)
```

Comment: That doesn't pass the test case `joint_support('apple', rows)`, which should return `5`. I think it's because the first `set` statement turns `'apple'` into `{'p', 'a', 'e', 'l'}`.

Comment: @GBR24 You have to set the first parameter as a list with one element. I have updated my post.

Comment: I know that, but I'd rather just pass `str`, e.g. `'apple'` versus `list`, e.g. `['apple']`

Comment: @GBR24 Okay I understand, but this is bad style. Once you run it with a list and once with a string. This is ambiguous. I would suggest to use two kind of parameters. `joint_support(items, string=None, rows=None)` Then you can simply test which one you want to use or you can even combine both to a bigger list.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually already figured out how to convert a `str` to a `list` without the elements being individual characters: `row.split()`. Your problem is that this leaves you with bunch of a small lists (like `['candy', 'apple', 'banana', 'cookie']`) rather than flattening all the lists into one long one that is easy to count. For that, you can use itertools.chain() as I do here:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> rows = ['candy apple banana cookie', 'candy apple banana', 'candy', 'apple', 'apple banana candy', 'candy apple', 'banana']
>>> words_list = list(itertools.chain(*[phrase.split() for phrase in rows]))
>>> word_counts = Counter(words_list)
>>> print(words_list)
['candy', 'apple', 'banana', 'cookie', 'candy', 'apple', 'banana', 'candy', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'candy', 'candy', 'apple', 'banana']
>>> print(word_counts)
Counter({'apple': 5, 'candy': 5, 'banana': 4, 'cookie': 1})
```

Comment: My intent must not have been completely conveyed above. I would like for the `items` parameter, I would like to pass either an individual `str`, e.g. `'apple'`, or `list`, e.g. `['apple', 'banana']`, to the function. The way the function currently works, if I pass `str`, it would iterate through the string (the `for item in items` part), as opposed to searching through a `list` of length 1 with the passed string as its only element.

Answer (score 1):

When passing a list of items, add a leading *asterisk* to the parameter, so the list is treated as a container of separate items:

```
def joint_support(rows, *items):
    if len(items) == 1:
        return float(sum(items[0] in row for row in rows))
    elif len(items) > 1:
        return float(sum(any(r in row for r in items) for row in rows))


rows = ['candy apple banana cookie', 'candy apple banana', 'candy', 'apple', 'apple banana candy', 'candy apple', 'banana']

print(joint_support(rows, 'apple')) # 5.0

# add a leading asterisk
print(joint_support(rows, *['apple', 'boy', 'banana'])) # 6.0
```

To count containment of all the joint items instead of *any* of them, replace `any` with `all` in the `elif` block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only checking whether all the items exist in the list, you can use `set` and subtract it.

```
def joint_support(item, rows):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        item = (item,)
    return float(sum[1 for row in rows if not set(item)-set(row.split(" "))])
```